Google Sheets sort in forms
I have a sheet with the data from the form, I move it to Sheet 2 where I tick the checkbox when I have completed the task. The data in Sheet 2 is sorted by date, when I change the date in the form response because it is wrong it changes its position in Sheet 2, however the checkbox still remains in the same place. How can this be corrected so that everything changes its order?
text
I mean about row H in Form, this date I change

Welcome to SO! Please always share your sample data as a text table.

Put the column with the checkboxes directly in sheet 1, inside the filter.

It is because the checkbox is not present on sheet1. If @user27425627' advice is not an option for you, I believe, utilizing appscript is the way to go.

@4thAnd1 Unfortunately, adding the checbox in Sheet 1 does not allow me to change its state in Sheet 2, which is necessary

Do you  just want the checkbox to move accordingly? or maybe if the date was change the checkbox will be set to false?

I want to move accordingly checkbox.

Are you open to an approach that will include the use of an app script? This might also alter the way you are querying the data from sheet 'Form' to 'Sheet 2'; the QUERY formula might need to be done inside the app's script as well.

Yes, I open, the QUERY formula can be change, more important for me is move checkbox when I sort

It sounds like your intention is to manually add data side-by-side with formula results. That exposes you to the risk of rows getting misaligned.
One way to avoid the issue would be to insert the checkbox column directly to the form responses sheet instead of adding it next to formula results. Alternatively, use vlookup() to look up the data from yet another table by some unique key you have in all the tables, such as the timestamp.
See this thorough treatment of the row misalignment issue.
